# How can I safely transfer files and run commands on a remote backup server?

Tags: linux, ssh, backup

I have a lot of data saved locally on my PC, and I want to set up a remote backup server for my stuff at a friend's house in another state. The data isn't particularly sensitive, but I also don't want people to get at it, either. I need to be able to transfer files and run commands on this machine.

I initially wanted to use SSH, but I wasn't sure if that was the right thing to use. What is the easiest/best way to set this up?

Note: Somebody will inevitably say "use cloud storage", but I have a lot of data, and it's expensive.

Note 2: I would prefer to use Ubuntu/Lubuntu/Ubuntu Server over something like CentOS just because I know it better, but I will learn CentOS at some point... If there is a really good tool that is only available for CentOS, then include it and I will figure it out

Comment: ssh is the right family of protocols, but I would probably want to put a VPN in place and ssh through it.

Comment: We some more parameters: The operating systems on both sides of the transfer, the data volume and the connection speed and reliability. Why do you need to execute commands? Can you take over the login of the target computer?

Comment: Client (My PC) is Ubuntu 20.04. The server is running Lubuntu right now, but I can change that if need be. I want to synchronize ~8TB of local data to the server over my 250 MB/s internet connection (It will only be 8TB in the beginning, I plan to use a custom script or a service like Rsync to reduce the data transfer volume to something more reasonable, maybe 150-200GB). I need to execute commands for management stuff, and in case anything has an issue.

Comment: @FrankThomas Why using VPN and SSH for that kind of job? The ssh connection is already encrypted. Adding a VPN here will only slow down the file transfer. Rsync over ssh is the easiest way to go IMO.